# How is Qi viewed in Judaism?

Tags: sorcery-magic-kishuf

Are there any Jewish sources which discuss [Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi) and some of the [amazing feats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3F3ovb2kZ9Q) people seem to be able to perform with it? Is it considered impure magic and therefore forbidden to be practiced?

Comment: There are some rabbis that argue that martial arts cannot be practiced for reasons of avodah zarah. You might want to consider looking there.

Comment: The WP page you linked to likens it to "*ruah* in Hebrew culture." That might be a good place to start investigating.

Comment: Rabbi Ariel Bar Tzadok argues [here](http://www.koshertorah.com/health-exercise.html) that the Chinese concept of *qi* "correlates almost identically to what traditional Jewish sources refer to as the *nefesh* level of soul within the body."

Comment: Duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35152/are-there-any-jewish-sources-which-discuss-the-existence-of-auras-or-energy-fiel

Comment: You ask if any sources discuss Qi itself, which is a fine question (and IMO not a duplicate, @Kordovero ). But if you mean to ask also for sources that discuss topics that might be relevant when evaluating Qi, then you'd need to describe (the relevant aspects of) Qi in the question.

Comment: I only know what QI is because the word always comes up in Scrabble / words with friends...